# SSRS/.net setup a dynamic where clause in the dataset

Tags: .net, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

**updated version**

[image]

Above is one of my dataset

My aim is to have the `WHERE` part , dynamic e.g. to appear or not appear, depending on what is generated by the `.net` code

Results would be like this

> `FROM table_name %string%`

Within `%string%`, there can conditions like this one

> SELECT Ent_SE_Devise,EntId_CodeJur_Code,Ent_SE_APE_ICS,Ets_Co_NonEnvoi,Ets_Code_Retour2  FROM TableV_EtablissementsListeActifs `WHERE cdt1 = 'test1' OR cdt2 LIKE '%somosa%'`

Or condition like this one

> SELECT Ent_SE_Devise,EntId_CodeJur_Code,Ent_SE_APE_ICS,Ets_Co_NonEnvoi,Ets_Code_Retour2 FROM EtablissementsListeActifs `WHERE (cdt1 IS NOT NULL AND cdt2 <> 'Yes') OR cdt3 IS NOT NULL`

Or no condition at all

> SELECT Ent_SE_Devise,EntId_CodeJur_Code,Ent_SE_APE_ICS,Ets_Co_NonEnvoi,Ets_Code_Retour2 FROM EtablissementsListeActifs

I created a parameter `@Iu_Ets` in which, `.net` code put strings like this

> SELECT Ent_SE_Devise,EntId_CodeJur_Code,Ent_SE_APE_ICS,Ets_Co_NonEnvoi,Ets_Code_Retour2 FROM EtablissementsListeActifs WHERE cdt1 IS NOT NULL AND col1 IN `@Iu_Ets`

It is not doing the trick

I have workaround now but to Anup Aggrawal, you said it is possible. Does what I've put in the question makes sense?

Comment: Use dynamic query, check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20815/Building-Dynamic-SQL-In-a-Stored-Procedure)

Comment: Hi @alejandrozuleta thanks for your comment. I'm just wondering if there is not a simpler way to do it ...

Comment: I think this is the simpler way to do a dynamic query.

Comment: oh là là ... @alejandrozuleta

Comment: Also note you can set a SSRS expression for the query text. So you can conditionally run a query.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta ... :) How?

Comment: In the image you posted at the right side look for Fx button, click it and you will see the text area to put expression you can use something like: `IIF(my_condition_is_true,"select * ...", "select *...")`

Comment: Why will the SQL/Query expression not work as Alejandro suggested? You can evaluate your .net code and then dynamically remove/add/alter the where clause as required. The only pain when doing this is that your query will need to be written as a concatenated string of text.

Comment: Hi @Kalim, I've never done that before and it is my colleague who is handling the .net part. This is the why. I' m more looking for an example , just to see what is possible. Right now , I feel like I'm looking to build a bridge and I've been shown bags of concrete and I've been told "well laddy, this is the first step". I'm more thinking of an example to see how it can be done.

Comment: I don't think theres any other options, other than the expression, should you choose to do the dynamic where clause in the SSRS report. If you would like an example of how to do a query using an expression then that can be provided.

Comment: Many thanks @Kalim. If you could provide, it would be fantastic ... :)

Comment: @AndyK Yes it is possible to have dynamic where clause.  Can you tell little bit in more detail may be with examples what do you mean by `depending on what is generated by the .net code`. I have written dynamic where clause in ssrs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a parameter to the report (not the dataset) called "Criteria_String".  The default would be an single space (no criteria).  You can pass WHERE clauses in to that parameter from .net, URL or wherever for your other scenarios.

Then in the Dataset Properties window, I would copy your existing SELECT code (not including the WHERE clause), click the fx button and enter the following:

`= "SELECT ... <existing SELECT statement> " & Parameters!Criteria_String.Value`

Comment: Hi @mike-honey, sounds like I have an answer ... let me double check

Comment: what do you mean by `The default would be an single space (no criteria)`?

Comment: An SSRS wont run until all the parameters are filled (they do have "optional" Parameters but the UI is clunky and usually avoided). Each SSRS Parameter has a Default Value setting.  I would set this to a single space character.  This would be concatenated to the SELECT statement without causing any filtering of the data. This would allow the report to run (e.g. for testing) without requiring entry of a WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the reason you haven't received an answer to your satisfaction is not that SSRS is rarely used, but rather that your question isn't specific enough to give a more specific answer, and a full tutorial on expressions is a much bigger topic than can be addressed here.  Nonetheless, I'll try to help.

The idea of the expression is that you can build up a string programmatically, from lots of parts.  For example, an overly simple expression might be `="SELECT * " + "FROM MYTABLE"`, which simply combines two strings, so that it evaluates to the query `SELECT * FROM MYTABLE`.

That example, of course, isn't particularly useful.  The power of expressions comes from the number of provided building blocks such as functions and operators, and the vast number of ways those can be combined to accomplish what you want.  To assist you, a list of those functions and operators is provided at the bottom of the expression dialog box that appears when you click the Fx button.

Without knowing what you are trying to accomplish, I and the other respondents here cannot give you much more guidance than this.  But I suggest you review the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx) on expressions.  In particular, familiarize yourself with the IIF function, which is a good way to include conditional text in your query.  Also, the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810706/build-dynamic-querydynamic-operator-in-ssrs-using-a-complex-query-updated) Stack Overflow question contains a nice discussion of expression-based vs. editor-based queries, and also includes another example of an expression-based query.

All of this might still be difficult for you if you do not have a programming background.  If that is the case, then you should consider enlisting the help of somebody who does, rather than trying to learn how to program expressions yourself.